# How can i form cron task based on bash query?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, cron

I have to do such command in crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * find /etc -type f \( ! -perm /o=w \) -exec sh -c "/bin/ls -hastl '{}' | tr '\n' ' '" \; -exec sh -c "/usr/bin/md5sum '{}' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 " \; > /tmp/crontable/daily/log/$(hostname)_$(date +"%F").log
```

but its doesn't make anything, cron doesn't execute this command, but in common shell it works well ,  what i`m doing wrong in cron? other cron tasks are working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` is a special character in crontabs (it signifies a newline). Try escaping it: `\%`.

From `man 5 crontab`:

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL
>          variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be  sent  to  the  command  as  standard
>          input.

Comment: i`ve change it but ot the same

Comment: Check your syslog please.

Comment: sometimes, you even need two backslashes, e.g. \\%F

Answer (score 0):

Step one would be to check the logs, usually it's `/var/log/syslog` (ubuntu, debian) or similar.

There are a few possible reasons for this, the most common one is missing PATH. Could you try adding the full path to the different commands? Ex: `/usr/bin/find` instead of `find`

Comment: there are others find commands in cron but they are working :(

Comment: Try saving your commands to a shell script, make it executeable.
And run the shell script from cron (with full path).